# "This organ contains three kinds of groups of cells"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, repetition

Is there any other way to say this sentence? 
I would like to take out one of the "**of**" in this sentence, because it seems too much. The sentence is:

"This organ contains three kinds **of** groups **of** cells"

Comment: There is at least one English word that means "a group of cells (with a particular purpose)".  Unfortunately, the word is likely to be confused with other (similar) words, so you will need to define it shortly before using it.

Comment: So that we can better advise you on the proper word choice, could you tell us what comes next? What organ, and what three kinds of groups of cells are you talking about?

Comment: And are you writing a school paper? If so, high school, PhD program in molecular biology? An article you'll submit to a scholarly journal? A chat with a 12 year-old child? Speech to a group of medical doctors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you could equally well say, "This organ contains three kinds of cell groups."

"Of cells" modifies "group" in the same way "of horses" modifies "lovers", and you can equally say "cell groups/groups of cells" as you can say "horse lovers/lovers of horses".